# connect commands trough pipes in a C Shell Linux

Tags: c, pipe

This is the function that I call inside the main when I recognize a pipe

```
void execArgsPiped(char* input)
{
char* parsedpipe[MAXCOM];
parsePipe(input,parsedpipe);
pid_t pid;
int in, fd [2];
int i= 0;
in = STDIN_FILENO;
while(i<nCommands-1)
{
  pipe (fd);
    char *toEx[100];
    parseSpace(parsedpipe[i],toEx);
    if(i!=nCommands-1)
        spawn_proc (in, fd [1], toEx);
  close(fd [1]);
  in = fd [0];
  i++;
  }
  if (in != 0)
  dup2 (in, 0);
  char *toEx1[100];
  parseSpace(parsedpipe[i],toEx1);
  printf(" command %i is %s \n",i,parsedpipe[1]);
  if (execvp(toEx1[0], toEx1) < 0) {
        printf("\nCould not execute command..");
    }
```

and here is the call to the function that spawns the process to execute the command

```
void spawn_proc (int in, int out, char **toEx)
{
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
    {
    printf("error creating process");
    }
    else if(pid==0){  
      if (in != 0)
        {
          dup2 (in, 0);
          close (in);
      }
      if (out != 1)
      {
        printf("the if 12");
        dup2 (out, 1);
        close (out);
      }
      if (execvp(toEx[0], toEx) < 0) {
        printf("\nCould not execute command..");
      }
  }
  else{
  wait(NULL);
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I compile and insert two commands connected by a pipe, the Shell goes into a kinda of **infinite loop** and I have to close the terminal because of that.

I really cannot understand what's wrong with the code, I don't know very much of C.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) -- part of the [mcve] definition is providing the simplest possible code *someone else can run* to see the problem themselves. We can't run a screenshot. Screenshots also aren't searchable, aren't accessible to people with screen readers, are wasteful of bandwidth, and are otherwise generally not welcome here unless their content can't be expressed any other way.

Comment: Also, please don't use the shell tag unless someone who is an expert in *writing shell scripts* (or in the details of the POSIX sh specification) can answer your question. Questions about *writing shells* are outside its purview.